# What is the maximum amount of multiprocesses you can generate with Pool?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.6, pool

I have a code where I need to implement a method to find the maximum on a list containing 1341 URLs, where I have to create a list of values I get from the URL entered  and find the max.

I tried using Pool to speed this process up, but I'm not sure how many multiprocesses I can generate. For example, if I use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
with Pool(10) as p:
    print(p.map(find_max, urls))
```

This works, but it still takes a very long time to get through the 1341 items in my list. So then I tried this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
with Pool(300) as p:
    print(p.map(find_max, urls))
```

I got an error saying that I'm opening too many files.
I was wondering what the max number I can put into "Pool(num)" so I can get maximum efficiency.

Comment: Just because they have it doesn't mean they aren't empty.

Comment: I checked the the last 5 URLs and they all had values in "price_usd"

Comment: What about the last 10?

Comment: I just checked again and I found out that the 5th to last element had null lists, so I fixed my find_max method by adding an if..else statement where it would only find the max if the list was not empty

Answer (score 0):

300 is too much to deal with for operating system since it becomes harder to fork a new process while there are already lots of them. Ideally you should use `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` number of pools. Providing more numbers makes it harder to switch context for CPU. Have a look at [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) topic to get familiar with it. It essentially means that if there are more than one processes for a CPU core, then CPU must switch between processes to make them seem like running parallel. Even if you have 32 CPU cores, 300 is too much to handle the context switching overhead. Now you may find a sweat spot with lowering 300 but it will just work for **your** PC. That's why `Pool` uses `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` by default hence I would recommend to use that.

if your `find_max` function is a light function(that means it doesn't need much CPU resource to run) then forking a process will be much expensive than actually running it. In that case, you should use a regular loop to do the job.